# i want to call custom method in phonegap by using javascript,how can i call

Tags: cordova

//I am new phonegap application,i want to implement one method in mainActivity,i want to this method in javascript,how can i call this methods in javascript.

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity 
{
    private HelloPlugin mc;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();


        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
      //  super.loadUrl("file:///assets/www/index.html");

    }
    public void customFunctionCalled() {
        Log.e("Custom Function Called", "Custom Function Called");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "asas", 1000).show();
    }
}

//html with javascript code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callNewActivity() {
        window.MainActivity.customFunctionCalled();
    }
</script>
<p>This is my first app.</p>
<button class="btn" onclick="callNewActivity()" type="submit">Button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways:

1.- The way kathir proposed, it's the "easiest" way if you don't want to mess with the mainActivity. Just create a phonegap plugin and put your java function on it.

2.- As you are already working on the mainActivity, you can use a javascriptInterface that allows you to execute java from a javascript call. Example:

On your mainActivity.java onCreate method put this:

```
yourCordovaWebview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "yourJavascriptIntearfaceName");
```

then the method you want to execute from javascript should have a `@JavascriptInterface` over it. Example:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void yourJavaMethod(){
    //Do somethig here        
}
```

That's all, now you just have to call the java function like this:

```
window.yourJavascriptIntearfaceName.yourJavaMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

hey its not possible in phonegap javascript cannot call directly java methods. so if you want write anything in java means you should use **cordova plugin** only...

[Reference 1](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html)

[Reference 2](http://www.plotprojects.com/developing-a-cordova-phonegap-plugin-for-android/)

[Reference 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html)